# Azure StorageClient versioning

Tags: azure, storage, azure-sdk-.net

According to this article:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/04/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal/

Old versions of Azure SDK libraries will not be support by the end of 2015.
In our projects we are using StorageClient.dll 1.7. However it is a part of Azure SDK 2.2.

So now, I am wondering if StorageClient.dll 1.7 will be supported or not and if we have to replace it with StorageClient.dll 2.0 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on MSDN documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn744252.aspx, 1.7 version of the library uses 2011-08-18. You would need to update to version 2.0.